# Corona force app to suspend

Tags: coronasdk, suspend

Is there a way to suspend app from code? Just like pressing Win + arrow down on simulator. Some event maybe? I want to use it for debug only, so it has to work on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You just can "handling" the system events, but not suspend the app by code.

```
-- create a function to handle all of the system events
local onSystem = function( event )
    if event.type == "applicationStart" then
        print("start")
    elseif event.type == "applicationExit" then
        print("exit")
    elseif event.type == "applicationSuspend" then
        print("suspend")
    elseif event.type == "applicationResume" then
        print("resume")
    end
end

-- setup a system event listener
Runtime:addEventListener( "system", onSystem )
```